# How can I make Neovim kill ongoing processes when I quit?

Tags: neovim, terminal

I'm setting up a nice development environment in Neovim. If I have a Docker container running inside a terminal in Neovim, I want that command to exit when I quit Neovim with `:qall`. Currently, I can see the container is still running.

How do I configure this behaviour?

Comment: What have you tried? What did you expect? What happened instead?

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers don’t run in terminals. They run in the background. The docker CLI orchestrates this. But there is no association between terminal and running containers. So it’s not clear how this could be done at all. (Note that killing a terminal, such as when you quit, should terminate any active processes in that terminal. It does in Vim for me, anyway.)

Comment: This is running in the foreground with `docker run`, though. I can ctrl-c to kill it. I assumed quitting vim would do the same

Comment: @tsvallender well, that’s important to put in the question then.

Comment: @tsvallender but I agree; quitting Vim usually kills active processes for me

Answer (score 0):

When you are running the Docker Command via `vim` , you should check the action when quitting the terminal.

Consider these & use which-ever works for your Case :

```
:term ++kill=kill ....  
:term ++kill=quit ....  
:term ++kill=term ....
```

You should also check out `:term ++close` settings , though I think `++kill` settings will work out.